# gitlabs copy/paste upload folder

Tags: gitlab

I'm creating a wiki in gitlabs, I copy/pasted an image into a page and it automatically uploaded the image and referenced it like this:

```
![image](uploads/84329e7811b5d2efb31b764c4767770d/image.png)
```

How do I access these uploads via the web browser to update or manage them? I've tried the documentation and it just goes on about default physical locations via a shell which I don't have access to (this is a private gitlabs installation).

Also, does anyone know if this is a permanent location or something wiped (e.g. after a server restart).

I've tried all variations of 'uploads' in my url.

thanks.